# laravel default logout not working

Tags: php, laravel

i used default laravel authentication and get user name into my form. but when i use logout it shows logout route and show error page expire .

this is my view logout code

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <!-- Authentication Links -->
                    @guest
                            <li><a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a></li>
                    @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                            {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                    </a>

                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                                 onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                                            </a>

                                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                                    @csrf
                                            </form>
                                    </div>
                            </li>
                    @endguest
            </ul>
```

when i click logout it shows me /logout url and it's not working. how can i fix this error and redirect to my /home path

Comment: Can you please provide the error you are receiving?

Comment: page expire error is related to csrf token. I think you should refresh the page and click on logout immediately.

Comment: error page is showing "The page has expired due to inactivity. Please refresh and try again."     This is showing localhost/logout route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `@csrf` by `{{ csrf_field() }}` in the logout form:

```
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
             {{ csrf_field() }}
 </form>
```

Your problem because there is no csrf token sent with the logout form.

Comment: Facing same problem . logout dropdown does not working.. it is also not work when i add this

Comment: @krish Checkout your browser's console for any errors.

Comment: @krish very nice to hear that!

Comment: If the logout must be a link, we can use onclick event like this.

```<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                               onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                             document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                {{ __('Logout') }}
                            </a>
                            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                @csrf
                            </form>```

Answer (score 1):

There are possibly issues with your session cookies.

This may depend on your environment but I have fixed the issue before by making sure that `config/session.php` file contains this line

`'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),`

Then remove the `SESSION_DOMAIN` line in your `.env` file

Then `composer dumpautoload`

Also, check your `APP_URL` in your `.env` is correct.

Answer (score -1):

I tried all the above and didnt work  but finally did it like this and it worked!!

```
php artisan ui bootstrap

php artisan ui vue

php artisan ui react


php artisan ui bootstrap --auth

php artisan ui vue --auth

php artisan ui react --auth
```

Run all this one by one and

```
npm install
npm run dev
```

again  and it will surely work